# Specific wording to describe an object's surface

Tags: phrase-usage, formal-language

I would like to describe the surface of an object (concretely a ball) in a scientific paper. At the moment my wording looks like this:

> (...) especially since the last change of the rules which leaves 50% of the ball's surface open to any color or patterns.

Is this wording correct? Basically I want to describe that the rules for some section of scientific work have changed. Formerly objects surfaces were colored with a single color, now there are specific rules for the coloring. In this sentence I would like to describe the changes for balls: now 50% of their surface has to be white, the rest is open to any colors/scenes/patterns.

How would one word this in the correct way for a scientific paper?

Comment: While I'm glad you've found an answer that works for you, you may want to wait a bit before accepting an answer - this post on meta explains why: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original sentence

> (...) especially since the last change of the rules which leaves 50% of the ball's surface open to any color or patterns.

might be more clear with the rule change as

> (...) especially since the last change of the rules which **allows** 50% of the ball's surface **to be** any color or pattern **while the remaining 50% must remain white**.

using **allows** means a different colour/pattern **may** be used, but not necessarily.

It is ambiguous whether the 50% must be contiguous or not.

Comment: Thank you! It must not be contiguous. However, isn't the doubled use of 'remain' messy? I really like the sentence, but wouldn't be better to end it like "*while the rest must be white*" or "*while the remaining 50% must be white*"? Additionally: is "*to be any color*" correct? I would have written "*to be **of** any color*".

Comment: Any of your alternatives for "white" or "any colour" are fine, it's only stylistic.  It's odd that the 50% **must not** be contiguous? So, half and half is not possible?

Comment: Is I read it, "which leaves 50% of the ball's surface open" means 50% is "available", but any smaller part(s) (of this 50%) could be colored, and these if small enough don't need to be contiguous.

Comment: Yes. It could be 100% white, it could be 70% or 60% white. Everything is fine, unless the white surface area is greater or equal to 50%. The rest of the ball can be colored with anything. A mixture of different colors or even pictures like a Nike logo.